# Sync Exchange Shared Mailbox with GSuite Mail

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, gmail, g-suite

I am going through the process of trying to get the shared mailboxes of Office 365 Exchange to sync properly with Gsuite Gmail.

**Background to the problem:**

We are a primarily Microsoft Environment so we naturally run Office 365 and Microsoft products. On every machine. Bar one person, who has a certain attachment to using the Gsuite Mail interface.

Ordinarily, I would explain to this person that what they want is unreasonable in a network that is primarily supported and backed by Microsoft technology and then follow up by overruling them at a management level if they don't cease and desist. However, This person is an Executive with the power to pull the entire network over to a GSuite system just because that is what they are comfortable with and with very little regard for rest of the company's operation.

Unfortunately, this means I need to find a way to bridge the gap allowing them to continue using gsuite while allowing features the rest of the company uses on day to day basis to exist and reflect on their interface in gmail.

I have implemented pop sync to their account. However, this removes the ability to sync read/unread status and keep it up to date. This needs to stay intact as this is causing dissonance at the management level because things they are reading and responding to are not being reflected for everyone else. There is a communication disconnect occurring as a result of this.

I have reached out to various migration and sync providers and I am waiting for their replies to this problem and by extension, I am reaching out to the community here. I am at a loss for possibilities.

**Summary:**

So the primary goal I am having issues with is syncing the read and unread status of emails between gsuite gmail and exchange.

I am looking at all possibilities including add-ons on either side however so far I haven't turned up anything maybe I'm searching using the wrong phrases. If there is a configuration somewhere that I have missed that would be ideal.

Worse comes to worst I may have to code up a bridge but I really don't want to have to do that.

Afternote: This is a repost of a question I posted in Stack Overflow - after realising it probably best fits in server fault. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994197/sync-exchange-shared-mailbox-with-gsuite-mail
If this is a problem please advise which area it best suites. I will act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In my per experience, it can't realize directly, Since Exchange Online and Gmail have totally different product schemas. I searched and didn't find related Office 365 EWS API for Gmail. The workaround in my mind is that adding user's Exchange account and Gmail account in one Outlook profile.